# Drop-Down List New-Window Open JavaScript

Tags: dom, drop-down-menu, new-window

I'm extremely new to javaScript and have no idea how to create a drop-down box that has the description of a picture. Once you chose on the picture another window opens displaying the image. Can someone help? What am I doing wrong? It's been almost 2 weeks on this one issue and I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

```js
    function display_image(selectedImage) {


      var selectionName =selectedImage.options[selectedImage.selectedIndex].text;
      var selection = selectedImage.options[selectedImage.selectedIndex].value;

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Lesson 5 Application Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>CIW JavaScript Specialist</h3>
<hr />
<p>
Select an image:
</p>
<select name="images">
    <option value="mountains.jpg">Mountains</option>
    <option value="sunset1.jpg">Sunset</option>
    <option value="trees.jpg">Trees</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be handle by onChange event on select box.

And if you want to pass the value of selected option then just pass this.value

```js
    function display_image(selectedImage) {
      console.log(selectedImage);
      //imgURL-create imgURL based on the selected image
      // here you can open new window and pass the image path
       window.open(imgURL);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Lesson 5 Application Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>CIW JavaScript Specialist</h3>
<hr />
<p>
Select an image:
</p>
<select onchange="display_image(this.value)" name="images">
    <option value="mountains.jpg">Mountains</option>
    <option value="sunset1.jpg">Sunset</option>
    <option value="trees.jpg">Trees</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong. No pop-up window from the drop down selection with the images.

Comment: Update my answer check. window.open();